# How can I enter the Hardware interface?

Tags: macos, mac

How can I enter this interface?

[image]

the snapshot is in a instruction book, but I do not know how to enter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

 Menu > About this Mac > System Report...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The interface is `System Profiler`.

I found a solution, I can use Spotlight and input `System Profiler` to open it:

[image]